# Select all checkboxlist in Popup using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkboxlist in Popup. I used a selectall checkboxlist items function in jquery. The problem is when I check selectall checkbox , it selects all the checkboxlist items in popup and also in the webpage . how to make it select only the checkboxlist items only in the popup.. My code as

```
 <td>   <div style="text-align: left; margin: auto;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectReportAll" runat="server" Text="Select All" onclick="checkall()"/>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkReportLst" runat="server">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
 </td>
```

My script as

```
function checkall() {
   $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').click(
    function () {
     if (document.getElementById('chkReportLst'))                    
   $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').is(':checked'));
            });
        }
```

Any suggestions ??

Comment: why don't you mark answer accepted if you have got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an ID to your `<div>`, that way you can narrow your selector to just the inputs inside it.

```
<div id="cntCheckBoxList" style="text-align: left; margin: auto;">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectReportAll" runat="server" Text="Select All" onclick="checkall()"/>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkReportLst" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

And the selector becomes:

```
$("#cntCheckBoxList INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',    $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').is(':checked'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is but before doing it you will have to add class="popupCheckbox" in checkboxes inside your popup

### jQuery 1.6+

Use the new [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function:

```
$(".popupCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
$(".popupCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
```

### jQuery 1.5 and below

The .prop() function is not available, so you need to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

To check the checkbox (by setting the value of the checked attribute) do

```
$('.popupCheckbox').attr('checked','checked')
```

and for un-checking (by removing the attribute entirely) do

```
$('.popupCheckbox').removeAttr('checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',
   $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').is(':checked'));
```

To

```
$("#any_parent_in_popup INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',
       $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').is(':checked'));
```

Replace `#any_parent_in_popup` with any parent elements ID which is inside popup, and contain all the checkboxes. If you dont have any, You can consider adding one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkall() {
   $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').click(function () {
      $("#chkReportLst INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').is(':checked'));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for you at the moment is that when you are selecting checkboxes with `$("INPUT[type='checkbox']")`, jQuery is looking at all checkboxes on the entire page, as you mentioned.

What you want is all checkboxes which belong to `chkReportLst`.

For readability, I tend to do this as a jQquery sub-selector, using the `.find()` function.

So, first select your checkboxlist, and then use .find() to select checkboxes which are child elements of that list:

`$("#chkReportLst").find("INPUT [type='checkbox']").attr('checked',
       $('#MainContent_uscOptionsPOPUP_chkSelectReportAll').is(':checked'));`